# Не работает скомпилированный код на c++ в VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Начал изучать `c++`, решил в качестве редактора выбрать vs code, для компиляции поставил `g++`, но после введения в cmd команды: `g++ -o TEST TEST.cpp` появляется файл `.exe`, но при нажатии на него от моментально запускается и также быстро закрывается, как это исправить?
**Код:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char s[80];
  cin >> s;
  cout << s << endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А операционка какая?

Comment: @Harry Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можешь добавить ещё один `cin >> s` в конце, чтобы консоль ждала пока ты что-то введёшь.

Comment: @Алекс не помогло

Comment: @Settings https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/introvideos-cpp
Второе видео чекай, ты так делал?

Comment: @Алекс создал файл json, теперь код компилируется и работает как надо, но через компилятор g++ только, через cl.exe не работает.